# Pointers. *((char *)y +1)

Tags: c, pointers

How does the `*((char *)y +1) = 42;` really work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int sum=10,*x,**y,***z;   
  x=&sum;   
  y=&x; 
  z=&y; 

  printf("Addresses before  : %d %d %d %d\n\n",&z,&y,&x,&sum);

  printf("Content  before : %d %d %d %d\n\n",z,y,x,sum);    


  *((char *)y +1) = 42;

  printf("Addresses after : %d %d %d %d\n\n",&z,&y,&x,&sum);    
  printf("Content  after : %d %d %d %d\n\n",z,y,x,sum);     
}
```

Comment: tip: rewrite that code to output the number in hex (`%x` pattern), and use a hex literal in the source code for `sum`, and `42`. You should also look at `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(char)`. Also, you might want to [edit] your question to include the actual output, and the output you expected.

Comment: I actually find that teaching people assembly coding helps them understand C better. Especially pointers.

Comment: Its more a question about how casting works in C!

Comment: The expression `*((char *)y + 1) = 42;` is not clean; you're modifying one byte of an integer variable via a character assignment. You'll get different behaviour on different platforms depending on whether your machine is little endian (Intel) or big endian (more or less anything else). I'm not sure that it is undefined behaviour, but it is borderline. You should probably print the data more carefully; use `%p` (or `%.8p`) to print the addresses; use `0x%.8X` for the 'content', assuming you're on a 32-bit system where `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(int)`. On a 64-bit machine, you'd need more care.

Answer (score 2):

Given `*((char *)y +1) = 42;` The first thing evaluated is the cast `(char *)y` so, `y` is interpreted as char pointer. Next step is the `+1`. With pointers such additions are overloaded so this means `new_address = address_pointed_by_y + 1*sizeof(char)`. So now we have the address of the second character, assuming `y` points to a string. Next step is dereferencing, so we get to the value of the character. Which is set to a new value. So all in all the second character of the string is set to the value 42, which in ASCII is a `*`.

Comment: Let's forget about the string. I tried to draw the whole procedure and this is what i thought  [link](http://i.imgur.com/aYw9Whw.png)

Comment: This is the most concise, to the point and easy-to-understand answer. The assembly code above is a total show off, and the one with the memory addresses is perhaps correct but too lengthy and perhaps it explains too much.

Comment: @NicolasMiari: I agree that this is admirably concise. The trouble is that we can see `int *x;`, `int **y;` and `y = &x;` so any references to strings are erroneous. The code modifies one byte in the address pointed at by `y`, which is the value contained in `x`, making any further references using `x` extremely problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how stuff *really works*.

Let's look at how the x86_64 assembly looks. This is from `gcc -fverbose-asm -S testcode.c` and I am adding more comments.

```
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .string "Addresses before  : %p %p %p %p\n\n"
    .align 8
.LC1:
    .string "Content  before : %p %p %p %d\n\n"
    .align 8
.LC2:
    .string "Addresses after : %p %p %p %p\n\n"
    .align 8
.LC3:
    .string "Content  after : %p %p %p %d\n\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    # Write the stack pointer into the base pointer register.
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    # Now we reserve 32 bytes for our stack variables.
    subq    $32, %rsp   #,
    # And store 10 into sum, which is 4 bytes from the base of the stack.
    movl    $10, -4(%rbp)   #, sum
    # This Loads the Effective Address (LEA) of sum into register rax.
    leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax  #, tmp75
    # And writes RAX into x which is 32 bytes from the base of the stack.
    movq    %rax, -32(%rbp) # tmp75, x
    # And get the address of x (which is -32 remember) into RAX
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax #, tmp76
    # And write it into y AKA -24.
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp) # tmp76, y
    # Address of y into RAX
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rax #, tmp77
    # And write it into z
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp) # tmp77, z
    # Setting up the printf call. .LC0 is the address of the format string.
    # The function call arguments are being set in reverse order here:
    # really looks like printf RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8
    movl    $.LC0, %eax #, D.2049
    # Note that these are all Addresses and these are just numbers: Stack Base -4, -32, -24 and -16.
    leaq    -4(%rbp), %rdi  #, tmp78
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rcx #, tmp79
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdx #, tmp80
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rsi #, tmp81
    movq    %rdi, %r8   # tmp78,
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # D.2049,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf  #
    # Set up for the next printf
    # Now look we're using MOV to get the values.
    # This just means to copy what is in Stack Base - 4 memory location into register EDI.
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edi  # sum, sum.0
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rcx # x, x.1
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx # y, y.2
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rsi # z, z.3
    movl    $.LC1, %eax #, D.2054
    movl    %edi, %r8d  # sum.0,
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # D.2054,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf  #
    # Here is the confusing line *((char *)y +1) = 42;
    # Copy y into RAX. Remember y was set to RBP - 32. 
    # That's the location of x.
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax # y, y.4
    # Add 1 to RAX. So now it is RBP - 31
    addq    $1, %rax    #, D.2056
    # Write 42 into ONE BYTE at the memory location RAX is holding.
    # And Intel is Least Significant Byte order so RBP - 31 is the byte that counts by
    # 256 or the second byte from the right.
    # And note that after this x no longer points to sum but to some other place.
    movb    $42, (%rax) #, *D.2056_8
    # And blah blah more printfs.
    movl    $.LC2, %eax #, D.2057
    leaq    -4(%rbp), %rdi  #, tmp82
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rcx #, tmp83
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdx #, tmp84
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rsi #, tmp85
    movq    %rdi, %r8   # tmp82,
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # D.2057,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf  #
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edi  # sum, sum.5
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rcx # x, x.6
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx # y, y.7
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rsi # z, z.8
    movl    $.LC3, %eax #, D.2062
    movl    %edi, %r8d  # sum.5,
    movq    %rax, %rdi  # D.2062,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf  #
    movl    $0, %eax    #, D.2063
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: all numbers are hexadecimal. The byte order shown is big-endian, although most PCs have a little-endian architecture. This does affect the output result, but is irrelevant for the explanation.

C's memory model roughly looks like this: The memory consists of a sequence of bytes, each of which has an address:

```
__ ... __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ bytes
 0 ... A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA AB AC AD AE AF addresses
```

A variable stands for some memory address, e.g. `sum` is equivalent to the address `A0`. A variable also has a type, which determines how large the memory segment after that adress is. For example, an `int` might be 4 bytes:

```
__ ...|__ __ __ __|__ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ bytes
 0 ...|A0 A1 A2 A3|A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA AB AC AD AE AF addresses
------|-----------|---------------------------------------------
      |"sum"      |                                    names
      | int       |                                    type
```

The `&` operator gets the address of a name, e.g. `&sum` would here be `A0`. This value is called a *pointer*, that is a memory address which contains some other value. After we run your initialization code, we have the following memory contents:

```
        v----------.v----------.v----------.
__ ...|00 00 00 A0|00 00 00 A0|00 00 00 A4|00 00 00 A8|bytes
 0 ...|A0 A1 A2 A3|A4 A5 A6 A7|A8 A9 AA AB|AC AD AE AF|addresses
------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|---------
      |"sum"      |"x"        |"y"        |"z"        |names
      | int       | int *     | int **    | int ***   |type
      |sum = 0xA0 |x = &sum   |y = &x     |z = &y     |
```

The `y` variable has type `int **`, i.e. it's a pointer to a pointer to an int. In the above diagram, a pointer is 4 bytes wide. However, we can reinterpret this byte sequence differently: `(char *)y` means that we interpret the value at the `y` location as a pointer to a char (which is one byte wide):

```
                    v----------.
__ ... 00 00 00 A0|00|00 00 A0|00 00 00 A4|00 00 00 A8 bytes
 0 ... A0 A1 A2 A3|A4|A5 A6 A7|A8 A9 AA AB|AC AD AE AF addresses
------------------|--|--------|-----------|---------------------
                  |  |        |"y"        |            names
                  |ch|        | char *    |            type
```

The `(char *)y + 1` adds the size of one character (`1`) to the value at `y` interpreted as a `char *` (`A4`). Together, that's `A5`.

The `*(...)` “deferences” that value, i.e. accesses the value at the specified memory location. In our case, this is `00`:

```
                    v----------.
__ ... 00 00 00 A0|00|00|00 A0|00 00 00 A4|00 00 00 A8 bytes
 0 ... A0 A1 A2 A3|A4|A5|A6 A7|A8 A9 AA AB|AC AD AE AF addresses
------------------|--|--|-----|-----------|---------------------
                  |  |  |     |"y"        |            names
                  |ch|ch|     | char *    |            type
         *(0xA4) --^  ^-- *(0xA5)
```

We set the value at that location to decimal `42`, which is `2A` in hex:

```
                    v----------.
__ ... 00 00 00 A0|00|2A|00 A0|00 00 00 A4|00 00 00 A8 bytes
 0 ... A0 A1 A2 A3|A4|A5|A6 A7|A8 A9 AA AB|AC AD AE AF addresses
------------------|--|--|-----|-----------|---------------------
                  |  |  |     |"y"        |            names
                  |ch|ch|     | char *    |            type
         *(0xA4) --^  ^-- *(0xA5)
```

After you've set the byte, you go back to the original interpretation:

```
                    v----------.v----------.
__ ...|00 00 00 A0|00 2A 00 A0|00 00 00 A4|00 00 00 A8|bytes
 0 ...|A0 A1 A2 A3|A4 A5 A6 A7|A8 A9 AA AB|AC AD AE AF|addresses
------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|---------
      |"sum"      |"x"        |"y"        |"z"        |names
      | int       | int *     | int **    | int ***   |type
```

*Only* the value of `x` has changed, all other values have stayed the same. The location of a variable is also constant. While `x` still has the type `int *`, it doesn't point to the location of `sum` an longer. Instead, it points somewhere far, far away, and accessing the value at that location could produce a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, `*((char *)y +1)` is just a fancy way to say `((char *)y)[1]`.